how to solve cargo build-bpf / anchor build error on wsl ubuntu latest version
error: failed to parse lock file at: /home/totdking/SolanaUbuntu/token_raffle/Cargo.lock
Caused by:
lock file version 4 requires -Znext-lockfile-bump
This error was gotten while i tried to run the anchor build command on my command line
I tried changing the rust version, using older and newer versions, rebuilt the cargo.lock file, added required dependencies to my cargo .toml, used several versions of solana cli, reinstalled the anchor, used nightly versions of rust all to be met with the same error

Please open the "Cargo.lock" file within your anchor project, manually update the "version" to 3 instead of 4, and try to build again.
The error "Caused by: lock file version 4 requires -Znext-lockfile-bump" might occur to Window users because the Cargo.lock file, which is generated by Rust's package manager (Cargo), is in a format (version 4) that is not recognized by the version of Cargo installed on the user's system. Many Windows users might have an older version of Rust installed by default or through older guides/tools, especially if they installed Rust via methods that do not automatically update (e.g., standalone installers or custom configurations). Anchor and Solana projects often require the latest Rust version to work seamlessly, as they use cutting-edge features.
